# Include Jars for jruby/rails on Trinidad

Tags: jruby, trinidad-gem

I'm trying to run my jruby application on trinidad.

Following the [readme](https://github.com/trinidad/trinidad), I included the trinidad gem in the gemfile and ran

`rails server -e production -p 80 -d trinidad`

When I access my server with a browser, it gives me an error message about how it can't find the correct class for my database driver, which is in `lib/odbc6.jar` and works fine if I run the project using WEBrick.  The error message looks like this:

```
org.jruby.rack.RackInitializationException: 
load error: /home/bdares/project/config/environment
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:oracle:thin:@(my_jdbc_connection_string)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Plz try to setup `$CLASSPATH` global var.

Here are few more details: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11130246/255633

Comment: I'm tempted to close my question as a duplicate, but it's really a different question -- albiet with the same answer.