# JRuby & Warbler - Include gem?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, jruby, warbler

How to include gem(timers) in warbler jar?

## App structure:

- myapp

  - `bin`

    - `myapp` (file)
  - `lib`

## `/myapp/bin/myapp` content:

```
 require 'timers' 
 timers = Timers::Group.new
 five_second_timer = timers.after(5) { puts "Take five" }
```

## Warbler build output:

```
 $ warble jar
 rm -f myapp.jar
 Creating myapp.jar
 $
```

## `java -jar myapp.jar` output:

```
 LoadError: no such file to load -- timers
```

(...)

Comment: possible duplicate of [JAR generated by warbler cannot access included internal JAR library](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11122130/jar-generated-by-warbler-cannot-access-included-internal-jar-library)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using bundler

```
gem install bundler
```

Create the file `Gemfile` at the root of your project and write the dependencies on it:

```
gem 'timers'
```

Now warbler will add the dependencies correctly.